# how to make search jtextfield like jcombobox

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a project to make database application in Java Swing.

I want to set a a Jtextfield  like the search box of browser.
all what i want to typed the first character and then all data appear

Comment: JComboBox is not appropriate because you have to click on it . You need a JTextField and a JList of the  same width. After each query you update the JList

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want something like this? I'm sure you can use this to build towards your objective (just needs a few edits/adds/changes).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    String dataInput;

    System.out.println("What would you like to search for? ");
    dataInput = scanner.nextLine();
    // Imagine this database involves the usernames of various people.
    String[] usernameData = new String[] { "jack901", "chimp00" };

    for (String loadData : usernameData) {
        if (loadData.charAt(0) == dataInput.charAt(0)) {
            System.out.println(loadData);
        } else {
            System.out.println("User not found.");
        }

    }

}
```